# Immutable JS and redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I am using `redux` with `Immutable JS`.
My `state` is a `Immutable JS` object, something like

```
const initialState = Immutable.fromJS({
    bar: 1
    foo: {
        bar: 'a',
        foo: 'b',
        foobar: [
            {
               ...
        ...
    ...
```

Now I have the reducer and normally I would do

```
export function foo(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FOO:
            return {
                ...state,
                foo: {
                    ...state.foo,
                    bar: action.value
                }
            };
        ...
```

But, now that I am using `Immutable JS` I need to do

```
export function foo(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FOO:
            return {
                ...state, // do I need to change something here too?
                foo: {
                    ...state.get('foo'), // this changed
                    bar: action.value
                }
            };
        ...
```

However, that messes with my store. I loose everythng but `bar: action.value`. It seems like `...state.get('foo')` does not equal to `...state.foo`.

How do I do it properly? Or am I using `Immutable JS` wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do just:

```
return state.set(['foo', 'bar'], value)
```

The array is the path in you object nested properties, the last one is the new value.

Comment: Ah, thats it. It should be `setIn`. And for others who stumble across this: Make sure not to wrap the return in `{}`, but in `()`.